# Movie about scientist trying to find evidence of soul

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

I am trying to find the name of a English movie set in the present.

The scene I remember is of a female doctor discovering her elderly dying patient is missing. She follows an ambulance to a mysterious lab where scientists are conducting an experiment into the human soul. Her patient is placed in a glass room and monitored by the scientists. When he finally dies she is the only one in the room who can see his soul. The dead man's soul is asking for help to move on and there are dark entities in the room as well. No one in the room believes her and she tries to help the man move on.

Comment: Hi, Roshe. You are off to a good start, but a few more details would be very helpful, such as: What year did you see the movie? Did it seem new then? Was it in English or another language? Did it take place in the present or the past? Where did it take place (Britain, the US, elsewhere)? How did the movie end? Everything helps.

Comment: Not what you're looking for, but [The Asphyx](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Asphyx) (1972) has a very similar theme

Answer (score 20):

It's a Sci-Fi short film called "[Laboratory Conditions](https://youtu.be/1N25e4Ss34Q)" starring Marisa Tomei & Minnie Driver. It was published on the [Dust](https://www.youtube.com/c/watchdust) YouTube channel.

Marisa Tomei plays the doctor whose dying patient gets "stolen" by some researchers in an ambulance. She follows them to a nearby laboratory and confronts them. The head researcher (played by Minnie Driver) explains that they attempt to prove the existence of a soul once and for all, by keeping the dying person inside a sealed chamber full of sensory equipment. She invites the doctor to stay and watch the experiment, to which she agrees.

I don't want to spoil much more of the story than this, because I think it's a pretty good movie and worth watching yourself. Like the OP already mentioned, the doctor is the only one who can see the soul for some reason. And there is a twist ending.